# PostgreSQL WEEK number incorrect?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I wish to return the ISO-8601 week number for a given timestamp

This command should return **2020 12**, but instead it returns **2020 11**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('2020-03-17'::date, 'YYYY WW')
```

[According to this site](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020), week 12 began on 16th March 2020.

[PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) says 'WEEK' uses ISO-8601.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Postgres documentation you site references the Extract function. But your query uses the [To_Char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) function which has its own documentation.  That will explain why you need IW instead of WW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WW starts the week numbering from the first day of the year. I think you need to use IW